# Matplotlib: change default legend loc and legend bbox to anchor

Tags: python, matplotlib

Each time to plot in matplotlib with pandas, in order to put the legend outside of figure, I have to do something like:

```
single_obj_trading_curve_instrument_toppercentile.plot().legend(loc = "center left",bbox_to_anchor = (1,0.5))
```

The later part

```
.legend(loc = "center left",bbox_to_anchor = (1,0.5))
```

is  too repetitive... Is there a way to set this to default? Thank you,

Comment: The name of your dataframe is 50 characters long. The arguents to legend you want to save are 40. So calling your dataframe anything with less characters would allow you to still save some characters typing.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["legend.loc"] = "center left"
```

However you would then still need to define the bbox

```
df.plot().legend(bbox_to_anchor = (1,0.5))
```